# Как клонировать контрол TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#

Сейчас пробую так

```
TableLayoutPanel tocopy = mainpanel.Controls[0] as TableLayoutPanel;
  TableLayoutPanel copied = new TableLayoutPanel();
                    copied.ColumnCount = tocopy.ColumnCount;
                    copied.RowCount = tocopy.RowCount;

                    // заполнение данными                
                    for (int row = 0; row < tocopy.RowCount; row++)
                    {
                        for (int col = 0; col < tocopy.ColumnCount; col++)
                        {
                            if (tocopy.GetControlFromPosition(col, row)!=null)
                                copied.Controls.Add(tocopy.Controls[col], col, row);
                        }                            
                    }
```

и в итоге индекс выходит за пределы массива

Comment: А почему в  `copied.Controls.Add(tocopy.Controls[col], col, row);` `tocopy.Controls[col]` а не `tocopy.GetControlFromPosition(col, row)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос актуален то можно так сделать

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var y = new TableLayoutPanel()
            {
                RowCount = tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount,
                ColumnCount = tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount,
                Height = tableLayoutPanel1.Height,
                Width = tableLayoutPanel1.Width

            };
            for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                RowStyle styleR = tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[i];
                y.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(styleR.SizeType, styleR.Height));

                for (int j = 0; j < tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    ColumnStyle styleC = tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[j];
                    y.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(styleC.SizeType, styleC.Width));
                }
            }
            var w = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls;
            for (int i = w.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var c = w[i];
                y.Controls.Add(c, tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumn(c), tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(c));
            }
            y.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
            panel1.Controls.Add(y);
        }
```